# Size limit for Azure Cache Service

Tags: azure, azure-caching

Is there also an object size limit to Azure Cache Service (preview)? I know that Azure shared cache has an object limit of 8mb and just wondering if the same limit applies Azure Cache Service (preview).

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for certain, but given that the colocated cache has the same limitation, I would be very surprised if the cache service did not.